# Spring boot app - 406 Not Acceptable error, works fine in local but not when deployed on AWS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am deploying the war file on AWS Elastic BeanStalk.

```
@GetMapping(path = "/getDashboardScreenValues/{emailId:.+}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@PreAuthorize("#emailId == authentication?.name")
@ResponseBody
public SuccessResponseArray getdashBoardDetails(@PathVariable(value = "emailId") String emailId) {
    // List<String> vehicleList = null;

        List<DashboardDto>  dashboardDtoList = null;
        SuccessResponseArray successResponse = new SuccessResponseArray();
        dashboardDtoList = dashboardScreenService.getdashboardDisplayDetails(emailId);
        successResponse.setHttpStatus(200);
        successResponse.setTimeStamp(FiksUtility.getIstTime());
        successResponse.setMessage(dashboardDtoList);
        return successResponse;
```

Also tried the below but same error.

```
@GetMapping(path = "/getDashboardScreenValues/{emailId:.+}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@PreAuthorize("#emailId == authentication?.name")
public ResponseEntity<SuccessResponseArray> getdashBoardDetails(@PathVariable(value = "emailId") String emailId) {
    // List<String> vehicleList = null;

        List<DashboardDto>  dashboardDtoList = null;
        SuccessResponseArray successResponse = new SuccessResponseArray();
        dashboardDtoList = dashboardScreenService.getdashboardDisplayDetails(emailId);
        successResponse.setHttpStatus(200);
        successResponse.setTimeStamp(FiksUtility.getIstTime());
        successResponse.setMessage(dashboardDtoList);

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
           .body(successResponse);
}
```

I am checking through postman. Please help

Comment: What do your Request Headers look like? 406 error code indicates that the server cannot produce a response matching the values defined in the request's  headers. You should see something similar to `Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*`

Comment: @rlwheeler.. Thanks for responding. Even with "consumes =MediaType.ALL_VALUE" , I get 406 error.

Comment: Issue resolved by modifying the endpoint from " getDashboardScreenValues/{email} to {email}/getDashboardScreenValues.